# How To Connect To A 3rd Party Bluetooth Device On A Windows Store App?

Tags: c#, bluetooth, windows-store-apps

I've tried PeerFinder class by Microsoft. After trying to use `FindAllpeersAsync`, I got the error `A method was called at an unexpected time`. After going through a few pages of results from Google, I realised by calling that method, I am essentially trying to connect to other devices via WiFi-Direct. What I'm trying to achieve here is to connect to devices via Bluetooth.

I tried looking for samples by Microsoft by searching `Bluetooth`. I found quite a few results. After filtering through the results, I realised there was only [**1 sample**](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/site/search?f%5B0%5D.Type=ProgrammingLanguage&f%5B0%5D.Value=C%23&f%5B0%5D.Text=C%23&f%5B1%5D.Type=SearchText&f%5B1%5D.Value=bluetooth&f%5B2%5D.Type=Technology&f%5B2%5D.Value=Windows%20Store%20app).

I found this [**thread**](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/b1f71dd4-ee75-4cd2-921f-5d4eadb31952/does-metro-app-support-bluetoothsdp-when-use-peerfinderfindallpeersasync) from MSDN claiming

> FindAllpeersAsync function supports Wi-fi direct but does not support bluetooth
>       on Windows 8, on the other hand, it supports bluetooth but does not support
>       Wi-fi direct on Windows phone 8.

Is this guy right or what? If anyone manage to connect to a 3rd Party device via Bluetooth, please guide me in the right direction. Thanks in advanced.

**Update**

I'm [**not**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13793342/is-nfc-necessary-to-use-peerfinder) the only one encountering this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't think this is even possible. Not for Windows 8 anyway, decided to switch to a WPF project.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it help, but I have found information about feature request:
http://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-dev-platform/suggestions/1716881-bluetooth-data-transfer-apis

Not sure what type of connection you need to use, but maybe this will give some push.